# Creating a HashMap from a file

Tags: scala

I am trying to load a 3-column file test.txt and create a HashMap from the data, where the first column is the key and the second two columns form the value.  Here is what the test.txt file looks like:

```
afpoafi,oiqfj,qoifejpof
qopifjew,qofie,qowiefj
```

Here is my code and the error it produces:

```
val invMapData = scala.io.Source.fromFile("/Users/Documents/test.txt")
val invLines = invMapData.getLines

var invMap = new HashMap[String,(String,String)]()
for (i <- invLines) {
       var temp = i.split(',')
       invMap = invMap ++ List(temp(0),(temp(1),temp(2)))
    }

<console>:20: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.mutable.Iterable[java.io.Serializable]
 required: scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String,(String, String)]
                invMap = invMap ++ List(temp(0),(temp(1),temp(2)))
```

I'll mention that changing the for-loop to:

```
for (i <- invLines) { println(i)}
```

prints out the values perfectly.  What is going wrong here, and why is it that Scala is finding an Iterable filetype when "i" is a String?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As aforementioned, operand types on `++` mismatch, yet consider this version with immutable collections,

```
val invMap = io.Source.fromFile("test.txt").getLines.map { 
  l => 
    val Array(k,v1,v2,_*) = l.split(',')
    k -> (v1,v2) }.toMap
```

The first three items from splitting each line are extracted and converted into an association onto a tuple.

Comment: I noticed in some cases in my actual dataset there are only 2 columns, not 3.  How does that change the val Array... line?

Comment: @user1956609 For the case of 2 columns, `val Array(k,v1,_*) = l.split(',')` and `k -> v1`

Answer (score 1):

You have two mistakes in line `invMap = invMap ++ List(temp(0),(temp(1),temp(2)))`:

- method `++` accepts `Map` argument but `Iterable`
- if you want add new key-value pair to your map use `->` to create pair and `+=` to add
  it to map.

Use `invMap += temp(0) -> (temp(1),temp(2))` instead of that line.